# Use case can lead to another use case

Tags: uml, use-case

I have the following use cases:

[image]

As the user moves through space (the application will run on mobile, so it really is about a geographical location), he can get access to a new resources, or lose access to some resources (or assets).

How can I model that cleanly in UML 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Wikipedia definition of a [use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case):

"In software and systems engineering, a use case is a list of steps, typically defining interactions between a role (known in UML as an "actor") and a system, to achieve a goal."

A use case is something that you eventually implement. 'User moves' is not a use case, there is no interaction between the actor and some *system*. Likewise 'has phone' and 'has PC" are not use cases.

Remember that use cases are primarily used for modelling the interactions of a user with a *system*. It looks like your use cases are preconditions or state rather than interactions.

Comment: +1. So what would be the use case when the user moves from home to work and the mobile phone detects that movement? I do realize the user is not interacting directly with the system, but is this not some kind of "implicit interaction"?

Comment: That is a concrete interaction between an actor (the user) and the system (a phone), so in that case 'user moves' could well be the use case. However, what are the goals of this use case? what does the system do with this information? use cases should have some result of value.

Comment: The goal is to get access to some resources (assets) and to lose access to others. Imagine the user goes to work: he loses the asset "kitchen", and he gains access to "office". The application domain is about the methodology "getting things done", and it's actually more complex than that, but I've tried to simplify my question.

Comment: Actually, the goal would be "finish task", I guess. But the point is that finishing a task can only be achieved if some assets are available, and assets become available as the user moves.